# I need help identifying the core of this elastic cord

Tags: material-identification

I am seeking to identify an elastic cord with a flat and folded rubber core that I use for restringing dolls. What is this type of core called?

[image: unknown cord]

Answer (score 5):

The product shown in the image is often called elastic shock cord. It is usually but not exclusively a rubber center with a wrapped fabric outer covering. The "not exclusively" aspect is because any manufacturer of elastic cord can call it shock cord. Bungee cord is another somewhat ambiguous term which will return from a search this same product, among others.

Comment: Thank you for that start. Do you have any information on the type of center present in my photos to help narrow down a search?

Comment: "Marine shock cord" is another name I've found it under. I've found it fairly extensively under that name on eBay when purchasing it for the same purpose as the original question.